# Disable code analysis while build via Devenv command line

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, devenv

I am building my VS solutions with DevEnv command line. However on  build it shows lots of warning related to code analysis. Is there any way I can specify in command line not to run code analysis for Devenv?

Thanks

Comment: have you been able to find a solution for `devenv`? I don't say for `MSBuild`

Answer (score 5):

Building with Devenv has been deprecated since VS2010, you should be using MSBuild.exe instead.

Whether code analysis is performed is determined by the `<RunCodeAnalysis>` property in your project.  You can override property values with the MSBuild `/p` command line option.  For example:

```
   MSBuild yadayada.sln /p:runcodeanalysis=false
```

There certainly should not be any reason why you get code analysis warnings in a command line build but not in an IDE build.  Your very short question provides no hints what the underlying reason might be.  A very rough guess is that you are building the Release configuration with an inappropriate rule set.

Comment: Even though I'm with you on this in general there are valid reasons to use devenv.exe instead of MSBuild. We're facing the build-order-is-incorrect-using-msbuild-bug (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/12/21/incorrect-solution-build-ordering-when-using-msbuild-exe.aspx) on a customer's build servers and therefore have to use devenv.exe. I stumbled upon this issue because I want to override the RunCodeAnalysis setting for our CI build.

Comment: VS2010 were msbuild training-wheels, don't get stuck on an old version.

Comment: Sure, if I were free to upgrade high-handed I'd do this first thing in the morning :) at the moment they are running Server 2003 build servers so I've got to live with it for the time being.

Comment: MSBuild doesn't work with extensions such as Visual Studio Installer Projects so unfortunately devenv has a large use case.

Comment: "deprecated" maybe too strong a statement. As of VS 2019 it is still supported. The documentation does say "For build-related tasks, it's recommended that you use MSBuild instead of devenv. ", but `/Build`, `/Project`, `/Clean`, etc. switches still work fine.