# devenv.exe creates empty bin folder with no Nuget package

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2022, devenv

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 to build a .Net Core 7 dll. The solution contains a single project. When I rebuild the solution I want to create a Nuget package. This works fine when I select "Build - Rebuild solution" from inside visual studio.

My *.csproj file looks like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
<Platforms>x64</Platforms>
<Version>2.0.0</Version>
<DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
<EmbedAllSources>true</EmbedAllSources>
<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
```

When I rebuild the solution it creates the file "bin\x64\Release[My Library Name.Version Number].nupkg" and the folder "bin\x64\Release\net7.0" with the dll.

I want to do the same thing from the command line. I'm using the instructions from [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/build-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/build-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022). My batch file looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" "[path to my solution file].sln" /rebuild Release /project "[folder of my project file].csproj" /projectconfig Release
```

This runs successfully, and creates both the "obj" and "bin" folders, but no Nuget package is created and the "bin" folder is empty. What am I missing?

Comment: This usage of devenv.exe was [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25103369/17034) 13 years ago.  Use msbuild.exe instead.

Comment: Yep, this works, a 2-step: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "[path to my solution file].sln" /t:restore /p:RestorePackagesConfig=true
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "[path to my solution file].sln" /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64
pause

Answer (score 0):

@Hans_Passant gave correct advice, the *.bat file is two lines (first line restores nuget packages that the library consumes, 2nd line creates the library + nuget package):

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "[path to my solution file].sln" /t:restore /p:RestorePackagesConfig=true 
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "[path to my solution file].sln" /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64
```